Hollywood horror movie about a boy with a fatal disease and about a mysterious house and a fog like substance
This is a hollywood horror mystery movie.
The film is in colour.
I didnt remember the release date.
The main character is a boy suffering from a fatal disease who is taken care of by parents.I doubt one of his parents is a doctor/nurse.
The parents bring the boy to a new house near countryside of America, but the house is filled with mysterious things. One thing I remember is an old autopsy room.  I didn't remember all the events taking place there but I remember the end of the movie.
Some mysterious substance will be revealed in the final part of the movie which looks like a fog.
In the climax the boy is completely cured from his terminal illness.

Sounds like "The Haunting in Connecticut"

"Charts one family's encounter with the dark forces of the supernatural. When the Campbell family moves to upstate Connecticut, they soon learn that their charming Victorian home has a disturbing history: not only was the house a transformed funeral parlor where inconceivable acts occurred, but the owner's clairvoyant son Jonah served as a demonic messenger, providing a gateway for spiritual entities to crossover. Now terror awaits when Jonah, the boy who communicated with the dead, returns to unleash horror on the innocent and unsuspecting family."

Preview: 

 
